# Android gradle isn't see host name

Tags: android, gradle

Android gradle is showing this error

> Host name 'repo.jfrog.org' does not match the certificate subject
>   provided by the peer (CN=*.fractalanalytics.com, OU=PositiveSSL
>   Wildcard, OU=Domain Control Validated)

My gradle is      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

Answer (score 0):

Try building/compiling while connected to a different internet provider. It sounds like your IT dept is doing SSL termination on your network.